# What is the advantage of supersymmetry?

Tags: supersymmetry

what are the advantages of SUSY with respect to other theories?

for example DIMENSIONAL REGULARIZATION can also deal with the UV and IR divergences too :D

so what other advantages has [supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry)?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451

Comment: Have you considered reading the wikipedia article on [Supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry#Mathematics), or glanced at the introductory chapter of any good Supersymmetry book. Most books start with a motivation. Aitchison's book is quite easy to read as an introduction, and there is a free .pdf draft from the SLAC avaliable [online](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-r-865.pdf). The short answer is that the advantages are vast.