# Can a rebranded super-symmetry be consistent with the null results at the LHC

Tags: supersymmetry, large-hadron-collider

To explain the null results on SUSY at the LHC, it continues to be assumed that the achievement of the energy threshold for the creation of the SUSY partners is beyond the capability of the accelerator that failed to find them.

Is it possible find a new perspective that retains a fundamental role for SUSY  and explains the null LHC results?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/2451

Comment: hey, mine: https://inspirehep.net/record/835121?ln=es https://inspirehep.net/record/699614/?ln=es but surely you are asking for a new _and correct_ perspective. And well baked.

Answer (score 0):

To explain those results from a fresh perspective, it is useful to observe, that even if one knew that SUSY is fundamental, that knowledge would provide no information on how the basic interactions manifest it.

There are at least two mutually exclusive possibilities.

In the first, since SUSY is an invariance between boson and fermion sectors, and all the basic interactions feature such sectors, it should be regarded as a common property of all interactions.

In the second, it can be argued that the super-symmetric fields are fundamental quantum fields in their own right, that, like the Higgs field, comprise a sector of the Standard model.

Since the coupling constant, the super-symmetric charge, appearing in an interacting WZ model would be a fundamental constant it could not be the charge on an electron or color charge on a quark.

This means that the rest of the interactions could not be invariant under super-symmetry or their SUSY couplings would be the electric charge, color charge, etc.

If so, for the simplest case, a W-Z multiplet consisting of only four particles, which is certainly appropriate to a fundamental interaction, would comprise the full list of super-symmetric particles--thus explaining the null LHC result on the grounds that the partners of the known particles don't exist.

If it is assumed these particle have zero weak charge, zero color charge; and zero electric charge, then the only necessary coupling to the other sectors would be with gravity.

Then, although they might only weigh 1ev, they would neither experience the destructive influence of the weak interaction just after the big bang nor would they register in conventional earth bound detectors.

As an a further feature of this scheme, suppose that the Higgs and SUSY sectors couple to each other through a Yukawa interaction that is not invariant under super-symmetry--as must be the case since it is assumed that the Higgs sector is not super-symmetric: U = gH(${M^i}^j$ ${\nu^t}_i$
${\nu}_j$ + ${s\nu^2}_1$ + ${s\nu^2}_2$).

Then, if spontaneous symmetry breaking occurs on the Higgs sector such that the Higgs field is replaced by H$_0$,and M is the unit matrix, the SUSY particles would start off massless and then acquire identical masses in the same way the electron acquires its mass.

This not how they come by that property in the usual treatment where the introduction of a super-symmetric mass term forces this identity on the classical field equations obtained by minimizing the resulting action.

At a next level of complexity, if it is assumed that there is one WZ multiplet per flavor, and the familiar neutrinos acquire their mass though the same interaction, then one of the multiplet partners would have the mass of an electron neutrino.

Evidence for this comes from a virial treatment of polytropes consisting of a BE condensate. Assuming that the dark matter in a super-cluster is comprised of a condensate of fundamental sneutrinos, their mass would be ~1ev.[@H.Cooper]

Moreover, if the M matrix has off diagonal components r such that e*= rg defines the effective interaction strength, an anti-neutrino of charge -e* could form a bound state with a Higg's particle of charge e*. If the coupling is strong enough, the negative binding energy might reduce the composite to zero mass.

Since all the neutrinos might form bound states through this interaction, it might be the case that QFT influences that would otherwise cause the Higgs mass to diverge are actually required to pump things up to the observed value.

Then, the SUSY partners of the familiar particles, that also might have stabilized the Higgs mass, could be dispensed with without loss.

If it were possible to cause a pair of hydrogen like Higgs Composites to collide at an energy high enough to ionize--eject a neutrino, the resulting instability might unleash a micro-burst of everything.

Finally, it should be noted that although the Yukawa interaction allows for the decay of the Higgs into neutrino/anti-neutrino pairs, phase space factors, ${m_\nu}/{m_H}$ (one for each fermion in the final state) coming from scattering theory, would effectively suppress that channel.

While a new channel is opened by the possible decay into two sneutrinos, the uncertainty principle suggests a decay into a quark/anti-quark would be faster by a factor of ${m_q}/{m_\nu}$, so this channel would be undetectable.

For the purpose of the astrophysical application, it is useful to note that the energy threshold for the creation of a Higgs by the destruction of two sneutrinos is too great for this channel to generate significant losses.

Finally, any evidence for the existence of sterile neutrinos, at the electron neutrino mass, might actually be the signal of fundamental SUSY neutrinos.

Comment: Write a paper and post it on vixra.