# Can supersymmetry be disproved?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, supersymmetry

Recently there are a lot of news about the plans to build the FCC accelerator, with many claims of possibilities to find new particles, for example like those suggested by theories of supersymmetry. However, this theory has been around for decades already, with no signs of experimental confirmation.

So my questions is - can there be an experiment, which we may perform with our current means, whose results will disprove supersymmetry, or at least will make it very unlikely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if the LHC doesn't see SUSY?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6438/)

Comment: For more recent information you can check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry#Current_status .